# How does one transfer information from one data frame to another matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I uploaded a text file into R called populationNames, which looks like this:

```
Abkhasian
Adygei
Algerian
Altaian
Armenian
AshkenaziJewish
Azerbaijani
```

I coded this in R:

```
outputTable <- matrix(nrow = 102, ncol = 3)
print(populationNames[5,1]) #this outputs "Armenian"
outputTable[1,1] = populationNames[5,1]
print(outputTable[1,1])#This outputs 5
```

Why is there a discrepancy between the two outputs if they are clearly the same?

Comment: Look at the structure of objects with `str()`. Probably your text file was imported as a `factor` class, and your matrix defaulted to another class. When you assign the factor to the matrix, it gets coerced to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the structure of objects with `str()` - you'll quickly see that your data frame has a column of class `factor` and your matrix at the end is of class `integer`. Probably your text file was imported as a `factor` class (within a data frame), and your matrix defaulted to another class. When you assign the factor to the matrix, it gets coerced to an integer.

Some solutions:

1. When you import your text file, set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` so it won't be auto-converted to `factor`;
2. It's best to fix when you import, but you can also correct the data frame column: `populationNames[, 1] = as.character(populationNames[, 1])`;
3. Initialize your matrix to be `character` class: `outputTable = matrix(NA_character_, nrow = 102, ncol = 3)`;

Any one of these will probably solve your problem. I would recommend doing both 1 and 3 - seems like good practice and clear intent.